# how to compare a record inside an array with another record in Ruby or Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, include, comparison, record

I have a method that looks for random answers and puts them into an array:

```
def self.answer_list(user)
  answers = Array.new
  for i in 1..25
    answer = random(user)
    if !answer.nil? && !answers.include?(answer)
      answers << answer 
    end
  end
  return answers
end
```

the include? method is suposed to not let the record go into the array if it is already there, but it puts it in anyway

How do I compare the new record to make sure something similar is not already inside the array? the record returned from the random method is something like this

```
 return answer = Answer.new(user_id: user.id, contact_id: contact.id, statement_id: statement.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ActiveRecord models are equals if they are not `new_record` and if they have the same ID.
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/%3D%3D

Here, the equivalence can not be set because your two objects are new records.

You have 2 solutions :

- define an `==(val)` function in your `Answer` model
- do something like that :

  ```
  if !answer.nil? && answers.detect{|a| a.user_id == user.id}.nil?
     ...
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question, but if you want a random N elements from an array, you can just use [`sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample):

```
user.answers.sample(n)
```

Assuming your user `has_many :answers`. I don't see anything that is obviously wrong with your code, `include?` *should* work as expected here I believe.